# How do I link libraries in VS C++ 2010 express?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, wdk, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to link some WDK libraries to my project in Visual Studio C++ 2010 express. When I look under the properties of my project, the properties window is pretty blank, (I don't have many options). Am I even allowed to link libraries to my project in the express edition? How do I link to these external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project (not the solution) and choose properties. The title bar of the dialog that pops up should say "[project name] Property Pages". It should not say "Solution [project name] Property Pages".

Then go to "Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General" and add the path to your libs to "Additional Library Directories". You will also need to add the specific library files to the "Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input" list.

Comment: While we are on this topic, I have another library question: VS C++ 2010 express does not recognize windows types such as UINT or BOOL. Do I need to download additional libraries to have these types defined? If so, what libraries?

Comment: Windows data types aren't included in projects by default in Visual Studio. You can add them to your project by including the Windows.h header.

#include <Windows.h>